# Smarty debug console in Jamroom

Tags: debugging, smarty

I have actually a problem in a skin i'm doing in jamroom.
The problem is that i want to use the {debug} to open the smarty debug console page where i see the template variables, but when i use that command it doesn't open that page and all the info is shown in the same page of the template that calls this function.
Does anyone knows what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reputation is too low to 'add a comment', so commenting here.

I've seen this happen sometimes when the code for the {debug} comes out in the  section. (as in the case of using the meta.tpl templates in jamroom ).

Try it in a different template, or copy the html code of the debug output to its own html file to view it.  Not the best solution, but works to find the variable your after.

Comment: At the moment, i use 2x {debug} one after another, as a temporary solution... using on diferent templates on the page is not solving right now.

Comment: Do you have steps to recreate what you are seeing?  I can try here to see if I can spot the issue.